# Visual Studio Code no longer jumps to errors in terminal with control click

Tags: visual-studio-code

Previously I've been able to jump to the error after running a program by control clicking on the error in the terminal window, but seemingly on restart this feature has gone away. Is this a setting I've messed with somewhere by accident or a key bind?

Update 1:
[When control + hovering it gives the 'search project for' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Iad.png)
that just searches the code for the individual word as a string. I checked my settings using the preferences -> modified preferences and reset them with no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines in settings.json file

```
"window.restoreWindows": "none"
```

Comment: The question was about "*jump to the error after running a program by control clicking on the error in the terminal window,*" This setting is for reopening files and terminal from previous session.

Comment: I had the same issue, after building the code I was able to see the error in terminal, but "ctrl + click" was not jumping to error location (line number). After adding the suggested code, it started working. Though I am not sure about the root cause or why or how it works. But for sure, I had the same problem and that helped. thank you.